# How to add a notification settings activity to the system settings

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-5.0-lollipop

On Android 5.0 there is an option through `Settings -> Sound & notification -> App notification -> Calendar (for example)` to go directly to the notification settings of the app.
I also know it's a flag in the manifest as described in this [DEV.BYTES talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uiq2kZ2JHVY).
How can it be achieved, what is the flag used?

Here is a screenshot for more clarification:
[image]

Comment: I would have expected to see something in [the app's manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml), but nothing seems likely.

Comment: @CommonsWare The Calendar app that takes advantage of notification preferences is Google's proprietary one in the Play Store.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to add the `Intent` category [`Notification.INTENT_CATEGORY_NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#INTENT_CATEGORY_NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES) to the `Activity` you'd like to launch through your `AndroidManifest`. A simple example would be something like:

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.packagename.YourSettingsActivity" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

For more information, refer to the Settings app and specifically the [`NotificationAppList`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/notification/NotificationAppList.java#L295) and [`AppNotificationSettings`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/notification/AppNotificationSettings.java#L88) fragments.

**Results**

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, just out of curiosity, how did you find it?

Comment: @Alex.F I looked at the source code for the Settings app.

Comment: Check my additions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28790754/android-lollipop-app-notification-settings/37054087#37054087 as to how to point deeper to a specific Fragment within your PreferenceActivity subclass

Comment: This isn't working on Android 8, is there an updated way to do it (my app is targeting 7.1 just fyi, maybe you need to support notification channels in Android 8 for it to work or something?)

Comment: @adneal how to open `app default notification settings` like its `subcategory`?

Answer (score -1):

```
  public void goToPushSettingPage(Context context){
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1){
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE,context.getPackageName());
    }else if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        intent.putExtra(ConstUtil.PUSH_SETTING_APP_PACKAGE,context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra(ConstUtil.PUSH_SETTING_APP_UID,context.getApplicationInfo().uid);
    }else{
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(ConstUtil.PUSH_SETTING_URI_PACKAGE+context.getPackageName()));
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't take it as a personal criticism but your post does not answer the question. The question was _How to add a notification settings activity to the system settings_ yet your answer is about starting an activity.

Comment: how to open notification category?