# Android Lollipop App Notification Settings

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop, android-settings

In Android Lollipop, when you long press a Notification, it gives you access to settings for that Notification's app, such as priority, or simply blocking it. Is there an intent that I can use to access those settings?

Comment: If you want to listen to notification filter changes, use the NotificationListenerService There is a listener you can use from it to detect when a filter is changed (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#onInterruptionFilterChanged(int)). If you want to be able to navigate the user to that screen from your app, use the intent INTENT_CATEGORY_NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#INTENT_CATEGORY_NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES)

Comment: Your response was kind of non-sequitur, NotificationListenerService has nothing to do with my question. But the Intent Category was what I was looking for.

Comment: @KyleJahnke did you get this working? I'm looking for some info about it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a notification settings activity to the system settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694719/how-to-add-a-notification-settings-activity-to-the-system-settings)

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer here - https://plus.google.com/+CyrilMottier/posts/YY6tbJrJMra

You need to add this to the activity you want to be attached to that settings icon

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the correct answer from @shmuel :

In case you want this "App settings" system button to jump to one specific fragment of your app's Settings activity deriving from PreferenceActivity, you can create a dummy intermediary activity to handle the intent-filter as details above, and then in this activity you simply do:

```
public class DeepSettingsFragmentDummyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        // Standard mechanism for a PreferenceActivity intent to indicate
        // which fragment to activate automatically.
        settingsIntent.putExtra( PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT,
            YourTargetPreferenceFragment.class.getName());

        startActivity(settingsIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

This code automatically launches the `YourTargetPreferenceFragment` fragment, and then dismisses itself (`finish()`) so as to not remain in the activity stack when the user hits Back.

Your Manifest must contain:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DeepSettingsFragmentDummyActivity"
        android:label="...">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: you can actually open the main activity as is, and check for intent.getCategories().contains("android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES") which will tell if it was opened from this button