# Can a preference screen be added to the Settings app?

Tags: android

In iOS, an app developer can create a preference screen with editable fields using the `Settings.bundle\Root.plist` file. This preference screen is accessed through the Settings app and not through the app itself.

Can the samething be done on Android? Can I create a preference screen that can be accessed through the Settings app?

Comment: Not in general. There are specific hooks for specific circumstances, such as [having Settings linking to a custom settings screen of yours for configuring your app's notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694719/how-to-add-a-notification-settings-activity-to-the-system-settings).

Comment: More than that- an Android user wouldn't even think of looking there for app specific settings if you did put them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Android does not have this option. If you want a preference screen you need to create by yourself like another Activity and if you need save preference data use the class `Sharedpreferences`.

Answer (score 14):

Android 7.0+ lets you have an activity with the `APPLICATION_PREFERENCES` action. This activity will be linked to your app's page in the Settings app, via a gear icon.

```
<activity
  android:name="EditPreferences"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The `android:exported="false"` limits access: Settings can start your activity, but arbitrary other apps cannot. Right now, [I am not sure why that works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39017482/115145), but it does.

I have a bit more on this in [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/17/application_preferences-security.html).

Comment: can we change the gear icon?

Comment: @Tara: I do not think so. Bear in mind that what icon is used, or even if this icon is offered, is up to device manufacturers, as they often revise the Settings app.

Comment: Actually i am designing media app for Automotive OS and i want to change he gear and search icon, may be we can change it, do you have any idea about AAOS media service toolbar?

Comment: @Tara: Sorry, I have never worked with Android Automotive. That is a very specialized area.