# How Can the Settings App Start an App's Non-Exported Activity?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-source, android-security

Android N lets you link an activity of yours into your app's page in
Settings. Just add an `<intent-filter>` for `android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES`. Android N's Settings app will look for the activity in your app that
has that `<intent-filter>`. If Settings finds one, it will add a gear
icon to your app's page in Settings, and if the user taps the gear, they
will be taken to your designated activity.

I was worried about security, and so I filed [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219995), looking for a permission we could use with `android:permission` to allow Settings to start our activity, but not allow other apps to start our activity (e.g., `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`).

cketti then pointed out that [you could just mark the activity as not exported, via `android:exported="false"`](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219995#c1). Much to my surprise, this works.

How can the Settings app start an activity that is marked as not exported?

I can certainly see there being a permission that controls this. However, a quick read of the Settings app's manifest ([master branch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml), [n-developer-preview-5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-n-preview-5/AndroidManifest.xml) branch) didn't turn up anything obvious.

So:

- Is there a permission that allows an app to start a non-exported component of another app? If so, which is it?
- If not, how is Settings pulling this off?

Comment: You answered something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892721/activity-exported-false-listed-in-activity-chooser

Comment: @Shaishav: While it is on a related topic (securing activities with `<intent-filter>`), it does not address the question that I posed here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would guess there is nothing in the manifest that gives an app the permission to call exported activities. I believe the way it's accomplishing this is by setting `LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true` in the Android.mk file for the Settings application. This flag will give an application system level permissions and place it in the `system/priv-app/` directory during OS compile time.

If you look at `frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityManager.java` for the method `checkComponentPermission` you can see that if the UID is that of the SYSTEM, component permission is granted regardless of the exported setting.

Comment: I buy the concept that it is based on the UID of the Settings app. I am not 100% convinced that `checkComponentPermission()` is the place where the determination is made, as I would not expect an SDK class to be deciding whether or not you're allowed to start an activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare What do you mean - `I would not expect an SDK class to be deciding whether or not you're allowed to start an activity`? What would you expect instead?

Comment: @Vikram: I would have expected it to be determined inside of a system service (`ActivityManagerService`?) or something to that effect. Now, it is possible that they use the same `checkComponentPermission()` method that is in the SDK.

Comment: I do agree it's a bit strange, it could be determined elsewhere. I did a little digging and it seems that other areas of AOSP do call into the `ActivityManager` `checkComponentPermission`. Such as `ActivityManagerService`, it has the exact method but delegates the logic out to the `ActivityManager`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see you point. Its annotated with `@hide` which tells me that it's not for public comsumption, and that it should have been part of `ActivityManagerService` -  which in turn relies on `ActivityManager.checkComponentPermission(...)`. Odd but, Bobbake4's answer looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

While @Bobbake4's answer that the check is based on UID is correct,

> If you look at frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityManager.java for the method checkComponentPermission you can see that if the UID is that of the SYSTEM, component permission is granted regardless of the exported setting.

I believe the first part about `LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE` is irrelevant. The directory location doesn't control which UID Settings get, but instead that is set by the [`sharedUserId` in the manifest](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/a8ee80e95af8a40ef565a275c4da7806a9378a2c:AndroidManifest.xml;l=5;drc=ae7422256792c2761d684459d610bebedf73334a). As noted in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid), this only works if the app is signed using the same certificate as the platform.